# Perl - Spreadsheet::XLSX -> New () slow on big files

Tags: perl

Given the answers from [this PerlMonks post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=912728), I assume there is not much I can do. However, I wanted to ask on SO since it's proven to be so helfpul.

Is there anyway to speed up how long it takes to Spreadsheet::XLSX to open a large file.

I have Perl code that runs very fast when I run on a small file (my test file was 9KB), but when I run it against a 5MB, it takes a nap on the beach before it's done running!

Comment: I hear your pain. It takes about 2 minutes to open a 1MB file on my machine with ParseXLSX

Answer (score -1):

You could use Devel-NYTProf to profile your code and see exactly why it is so slow.

Maybe you could find a bottleneck somewhere.

Comment: It turns out the bottleneck is Spreadsheet::XLSX's use of XML::Twig. The author of XML::Twig provides some hints here about how a speed up might be made https://github.com/doy/spreadsheet-parsexlsx/issues/65